# Identify part marked 'Z14' or '214'

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

Need help identifying the 6 pins SMD IC. This is a push button controller for servos with LEDs to identify position. Appears to say either **Z14** or **214**.

*Close up:*
[image]

*Bottom:*
[image]

<sup>Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huC9D.jpg</sup>

*Top:*
[image]

<sup>Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVT6c.jpg</sup>

Comment: What are the markings? It looks like "214"? Please review our [ID guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines) and [edit] your question.

Comment: Maybe the MUN5314DW1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [NC7WZ14P6X](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nc7wz14-d.pdf) from ONSEMI (SOT-363).

Unfortunately i couldn't find any picture with your marking.
If you look in internet you'll find old markings because originally it was a Fairchild product.
However with that [PCN](https://www.mouser.com/PCN/On_Semiconductor_Final_PCN_Document_FPCN23285X.pdf) you have the confirmation that the marking matches with the datasheet and your photo.

Comment: Thank you for the info.